# Get a session variable in property

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

I am using Mule Version 3.4.1 and I am trying to set a property and placing a session variable value inside that property, using MessageProperties component, but am failing with every try.

and I did not find any solution for it. Maybe any one can help?

```
<add-message-property key="mykey" value="valuex/#[variablename]"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `set-property` to set the property.

The solution for your scenario would be like

```
<set-property propertyName="myKey" value="#[sessionVars['sessionvariablename']]"></set-property>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<set-session-variable variableName="variable" value="#[expression]"/>`
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Session+Variable+Transformer+Reference

But this should also to the trick.

```
<message-properties-transformer scope="session">            
    <add-message-property key="name" value="#[expression]"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
```

If neither is working, you might have a syntax error in your expression.

**Update**

If I understand your question correctly, you'll need an expression like this:

```
#[string:random text #[sessionVars.mySessionVariable]]
```

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/MEL+Cheat+Sheet
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Non-MEL+Expressions+Configuration+Reference

Comment: The session is set, but I want to update the property with the updated value of the session variable that I have.

Comment: Don't MEL and old style expression evaluators. It may work but it's recommended. Prefer: `#['random text'+sessionVars.mySessionVariable]`

Comment: I didn't know that that's recommended, but it's at least much cleaner/ simpler. Good for pointing that out :)